# New Django virtual environment shows modules previously installed on system

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv

I have started a new Django project and created a virtual environment. After creating this virtual environment I used the pip freeze command to verify that no modules had been installed within it.

However, I found that all of the modules that I have previously installed in my system are now within my new virtual environment.

Obviously they aren't supposed to be there.. Where did I go wrong

I followed this websites instructions exactly: https://realpython.com/django-setup/

Here is what I am looking at (venv deactivated):

```
C:\>pip freeze
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.8
mysql-connector-python==8.0.21
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.2
```

(venv activated)

```
(env) C:\Users\wisenickel\nohtyPProjects\Serenata_Farms_Folder>pip freeze
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.8
mysql-connector-python==8.0.21
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.27

(env) C:\Users\wisenickel\nohtyPProjects\Serenata_Farms_Folder>
```

I did not manually install these packages within my virtual environment.

Thank you to anyone who is willing to help.

Comment: You validated that by using the pip freeze command you were with the virtual environment active. (It would be convenient to add screenshots of what you get)

Comment: @DiegoAaron Thank you for your response, I just updated my question with what I am looking at

Comment: Did you rename(or move) your project's folder? I had [the same issue](https://www.salvicode.com/post/do-not-move-your-python-project-folder/) since virtualenv's internal paths are "hardcoded" and when you rename or move your project's folder virtualenv works incorrectly(even if it shows `(env)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your dependencies(libraries) are installed before `virtualenv` activated too(which is in your global environment).

In your `virtualenv` activated, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. It will make all the dependencies written in `requirements.txt` file(Later you can install these by running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in one go if you happened to delete them somehow).

Then `deactivate`. Try uninstall one dependency in your global environment(no virtualenv setting) by running `pip uninstall Django`. See if dependencies in global setting are different than virtualenv setting. if yes, uninstall unwanted dependencies by running like this: `pip uninstall dependency1 dependency2 ... dependencyN`(use space between then, and pip will take care of them removed).

Now those will have been removed, there will be no confusion hopefully.

Comment: I know I am a little late but thank you for your help, this definitely worked for me. However after doing some reading, specifically this website: https://medium.com/@krishnaregmi/pipenv-vs-virtualenv-vs-conda-environment-3dde3f6869ed I have now switched from using vitrualevnv to using pipenv, which has much more functionality. Thank you again for the help!